# How to change the text label of a toolbar button

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a button defined like this:

```
        <Button x:Name="ButtonPlayMax"
            Click="ButtonPlayMax_Click"
            Style="{StaticResource PlayVideoAppBarButtonStyle}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            FontSize="17.333"
            Margin="0"/>

        <Style x:Key="PlayVideoAppBarButtonStyle"
           TargetType="ButtonBase"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
           <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId"
                Value="PlayVideoAppBarButton" />
           <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name"
                Value="Play" />
           <Setter Property="Content"
                Value="&#xE102;" />
        </Style>
```

The text label of the button is set to "Play".

Is there a way to change dynamically in code the text label to "Stop" or I would have to define a second button and switch between them?

Thx

Comment: Ya you'll just set a new text property for the button, ie ButtonPlayMax.Text = "blah"

Comment: I think you need to switch between styles Play... and Stop.., not only text.

Comment: I tend to believe that switching between styles will be needed as I tried the simple solutions....

Comment: @eitanbarazani, switching of Style property is not harder than of Text property :)

Comment: Ya switching styles is overkill and not necessary.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been much quicker to just try it, rather than wasting time, asking a question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of IL_Agent was correct. I did switch the style. The difference in the 2 styles wad just the required text for PLAY and STOP. Sorry not to close the issue earlier.